# How could I prevent a hidden component from reappearing when a state hook updates? (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an application with a popup that gives a notice. I want this popup to only show up once, but when ever I do anything that requires a state hook or effect hook, it reappears even though it shouldn't.

I tried:

- saving the closed state to a state hook and only rendering if closed==false
- saving the closed state to a normal variable and only rendering if closed==false
  Both of these solutions were deemed fruitless. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please post some minimal code so its easier to grab the exact motive of your question.
If you want to open a notice dialog only once but due to `useEffect` hook it gets activated everytime hook's dependency is changed then i think you can play with some other variables around for example...

```
const[openOnce,setOpenOnce]=useState(false)


useEffect(() => {
if(!serOpenOnce){
yourDialogOpeningFunction()
setOpenOnce(true)
}

},[...your neeeded dependency])


const yourDialogOpeningFunction =()=> {

}
```